# pip could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.2.1

Tags: django, linux, pip

I just have changed my os to linux and I want to install django. 
But I am unable to install the latest version of django.

I have tried 
pip install django However it installed django 1.11.11 which is not what I need. 
I also upgraded my pip to 19.1
However still I am unable to run the command pip install django==2.2.1

When I run the command this is what I see
$ pip install django==2.2.1
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting django==2.2.1
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.2.1 (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.4.21, 1.4.22, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.7.9, 1.7.10, 1.7.11, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.8.6, 1.8.7, 1.8.8, 1.8.9, 1.8.10, 1.8.11, 1.8.12, 1.8.13, 1.8.14, 1.8.15, 1.8.16, 1.8.17, 1.8.18, 1.8.19, 1.9a1, 1.9b1, 1.9rc1, 1.9rc2, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.9.4, 1.9.5, 1.9.6, 1.9.7, 1.9.8, 1.9.9, 1.9.10, 1.9.11, 1.9.12, 1.9.13, 1.10a1, 1.10b1, 1.10rc1, 1.10, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.10.4, 1.10.5, 1.10.6, 1.10.7, 1.10.8, 1.11a1, 1.11b1, 1.11rc1, 1.11, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.11.4, 1.11.5, 1.11.6, 1.11.7, 1.11.8, 1.11.9, 1.11.10, 1.11.11, 1.11.12, 1.11.13, 1.11.14, 1.11.15, 1.11.16, 1.11.17, 1.11.18, 1.11.20)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==2.2.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Django versions 2 are compatible only with python3. So to install in your system install it with

```
pip3 install django
```

or if you want to create a virtual environment

```
python3 -m venv virtualenv
source virtualenv/bin/activate
pip install django (this installs with python3 pip)
```

Comment: On Windows 10, when I run `py --version`, I get `Python 3.8.8`, but when I run `py -m pip install Django`, I get `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django` and `ERROR: No matching distribution found for Django`. Is Python 3.8.8 not enough to install the latest Django? What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

It seems like you are using **Python 2.7**, and the last Django version to support **Python 2** is ***Django 1.11***. To use the newer Django versions you need to uprade to **Python 3**.

Chances are you already have **Python 3** shipped with your Linux distro, you can check by running ***python3*** in your shell. It is recommended that you create a  virtual env for your project. You can create a **Python 3** virtual env with the following command -

```
python3 -m venv env
```

Activate your env -

```
source ./env/bin/activate
```

Now you should be able to install newer Django version in your virtual env -

```
pip install django==2.2.1
```

This link might be of help in upgrading your Python version - https://docs.python-guide.org/starting/install3/linux/

Comment: Your solution does not work but you give me the idea to use pip3 instead of pip which uses python-2. thanks:)

Comment: Can you tell me which part didn't work exactly. I've noticed I mistakenly said you should cd into your env, but I've edited that now.

Comment: I was ubable to activate.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pip install -U django==2.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows and the error mentions something like:

```
... Connection aborted.', PermissionError ...
```

Make sure you open the CMD with "Run as Administrator"